# qsystemtray menu is not hiding when the application stopped

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

```
trayiconContextMenu = QtGui.QMenu()
trayiconContextMenu.addAction("Exit")
trayicon.setContextMenu(trayiconContextMenu)
```

In pyqt, a context menu is attached to the system tray icon.
In a particular scenario, application exit is called internally, but at that time if the system tray menu is popped up manually, application will not be exit.

After pressing `Esc` key or clicking mouse in some other app (i.e) when tray menu is hidden, application exit will be called with errors.

```
trayiconContextMenu.hide()
/*does not work in my above case.*/
trayicon.hide()
/*hides tray icon alone but not the tray menu*/
```

Also for same scenario app exit works properly when tray menu is not popped up.

Help would be appreciated much.

Comment: What function are you calling to exit application? e.g. `sys.exit` will close context menu.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Win32. `sys.exit` and `QtGui.qApp.exit()` closes app immediately when context menu visible.

Comment: Well I can reproduce it in my mac. sorry delayed info on OS type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `QSystemTrayIcon` doesn't take ownership of the menu when you set it, so you might need to take steps to ensure it is deleted properly.

Try something like this:

```
trayiconContextMenu = QtGui.QMenu()
trayiconContextMenu.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
...
trayiconContextMenu.close()
QtGui.qApp.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks, But tray menu is not getting hide and also my app does not stop though i call QtGui.qApp.quit() directly when needed as the tray menu is popped up and scrolled through the tray menu.